# How to position and resize window that is opened by React

Tags: reactjs

When you start a React App, a browser window is opened to display the application's content. How can I change the position and dimensions of that window before it opens?

Comment: You mean browser window opening project for Create React App?

Comment: Not specifying a particular browser, but modifying the browser that is opened when you do your "npm start" command. I want the browser to open to a specific height and width, and have it position at the top-left corner of the screen or (0,0). Does that answer your question?